# How to pass id for call api in react native or get unique id on press of image?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
  <ScrollView horizontal pagingEnabled snapToInterval={200}>
              {this.state.json_arr.map((item, index) => (
                <View
                  
                  key={item.user_id}
                  style={{
                    paddingBottom: 40,
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    alignItems: "center",
                    padding: 5
                  }}
                >
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.fullsize_image}>
                    <Image
                   
                    source={{ uri: this.state.url + item.image }}
                    style={{ width: 380, height: 400 }}
                    />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  <View
                    style={{
                      flexDirection: "row",
                      paddingBottom: 50,
                      position: "absolute",
                      top: 0,
                      marginTop: 320,
                      left: 0,
                      right: 0,
                      bottom: 0,
                      justifyContent: "center",
                      alignItems: "center"
                    }}
                  >
                    <Text style={{ color: "white", fontSize: 22 }}>
                     {item.user_id}.
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={{ color: "white", fontSize: 22 }}>
                      {item.age}.
                    </Text>
                    <Text
                      style={{ color: "red", paddingLeft: 5, fontSize: 22 }}
                    >
                      {item.nick_name}
                    </Text>
                    <Text
                      style={{ color: "red", paddingLeft: 5, fontSize: 22 }}
                    >
                      {" "}
                      {item.user_location}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                </View>
              ))}
            </ScrollView>
```

In the above code I mapping a array and getting data like image , user_id etc. but I need user set to state for call another api using this id. suppose when i press image than id of this image generated and pass for call api.below I attached a image in which comment, like option avaiale when comment on paticular image than comment should save for this user_id. so please guide how to make logic for that.

[image: plese view this]

Comment: you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/uniqid to get unique id every time

Comment: I need user id getting from array uniquely when press first image than id should be of first image like that. is this possible in that package.

Comment: @AtulTiwari do you want to get item.user_id in the click of the image? right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right there on  Tag which write a function to carry the event handler function which in turn calls a util to send this id to API as below

```
<Image onPress = {() => api.sendToAPI(item.id);}
            source={{ uri: this.state.url + item.image }}
                style={{ width: 380, height: 400 }}
```

>

Comment: what is means of api in above code   api.sendToAPI(item.id);

Comment: i assume you have side .js file which you use to communicate with server, and on it you have declared objects, say api which have function to communicate with server i.e sending pic id